# Column in SQL table with reference to multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have a table `Page [Id, Name]`. And table `Element[Id, PageId, ViewId, ViewType, Order]`, where `ViewType` is name one of the tables: Portfolio, Fund, Position. And `ViewId` is id of element in relevant table: PortfolioView, FundView, PositionView.

View tables looks like: `[Id, PortfolioId, ShowName, ShowYTD, ShowMTD and other]`. When I create an item of Element it means that created item of one of the "view" tables.

So for me it looks like a antipattern.

In short, I wish create a model of Page, which contains a ordered Elements which represent a one of the Views (portfolio, fund or position). Which way is better to do it in sql?

Answer (score 1):

The way I've seen this done is to update your Element table with a column for each of Portfolio, Fund, and Position. The columns need to be nullable, but they'll be legal foreign keys, so SQL will enforce foreign key correctness for you.

If you want to be as technically correct as possible, you could also do the following:

```
Page[Id, Name]
Element[Id, PageId, ViewId, ViewType, Order]
Element_Portfolio[ElementId, PortfolioId]
Element_Fund[ElementId, FundId]
Element_Position[ElementId, PositionId]
Portfolio[...]
Fund[...]
Position[...]
```

This avoid having nullable columns, but requires you to have more tables and therefore more joins when you do a query.

Comment: Thank you, i think about this, but i don't like that in sush a case can be ambigiuous when several columns with ViewId will be different from null (or will be several rows in Element_* tables with the same ElementId). But if i don't find a better way i will do like you say.